# Cumulative sum on time interval

Tags: mysql

Following is users table

```
---------------------------------------
|   uid   |            reg_date        |
---------------------------------------
| 1       |      2011-07-20 02:24:36   |
---------------------------------------
| 2       |      2012-10-03 07:37:43   |
---------------------------------------
|   ...   |      ... ... ... ... ...   |
---------------------------------------
| 300000  |      2015-12-19 04:13:51   |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to get last 1 year from curdate() data by month basis from this table.

I have tried following query.

```
SELECT month, 
       @cnt := @cnt + total cum_sum
  FROM (
        SELECT MONTH(reg_date) month,
               COUNT(*) total
               FROM users
               WHERE reg_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
               GROUP BY YEAR(reg_date), MONTH(reg_date)
       ) n, (SELECT @cnt := 0) users_alias
```

but it generates last twelve months data as there were no data before that. But I want it to be start from actual cumulative count at that month. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

desired output

```
-----------------------
|  month  |   cum_sum |
-----------------------
| 10      |      1000 |
-----------------------
| 11      |      1500 |
-----------------------
| 12      |      2550 |
-----------------------
| 1       |      9700 |
-----------------------
| 2       |     11000 |
-----------------------
| 3       |     14000 |
-----------------------
| 4       |     15700 |
-----------------------
| 5       |     20000 |
-----------------------
| 6       |     22000 |
-----------------------
| 7       |     27000 |
-----------------------
| 8       |     31000 |
-----------------------
| 9       |     35000 |
-----------------------
| 10      |     41000 |
-----------------------
```

Comment: Could you show your table schema and give an example of the output you'd like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize @cnt variable to 0 at the end of the sql statement:

```
(SELECT @cnt := 0) users_alias
```

You need to change this to initialize the counter to the number of users registered before:

```
(SELECT @cnt := count(*) from users
 where regdate<CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) users_alias
```